# How to catching Unhandled Exceptions in Console application

Tags: c#, exception, console-application

I often find unhandled exceptions in my console application. Then later it hangs and stops all processes. I'm also forced to restart the program before it will work normally.

Unhandled Exception:

My program is a server program. I don't want it to stop working, because it affects the business.

How can I handle this error?

Comment: `try` `catch` is the best bet

Comment: An unhandled exception is an unexpected and ununderstood exception. Do you really want to write to your database after something unknown went wrong? Stopping the application is a feature, not a problem.

Comment: You should handle exceptions you understand and expect at the right places.

Comment: try - catch(Exception) should do the job. But catching all exceptions is a design smell for a reason. Please see the link: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164256/is-catching-general-exceptions-really-a-bad-thing

Comment: I've already try catch. But it's might not cover this situation. So I get this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register a global exception handler in your main method like this:

```
//Add handler to handle the exception raised by additional threads
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

Then handle all the unhandled exception in `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` method.

```
private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    //Your logic here, for ex., log the exception somewhere
}
```

Comment: An do write the value of `e.IsTerminating`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I add function and just log information then force to exit program always. I'll add command Console.ReadLine(); but I don't know that have another side effect or not? like memory or performance.